# How exactly do I do a barrel roll?

Tags: race-the-sun

In *Race the Sun*, you gain levels by completing certain goals. One such goal is "Do a barrel roll 20 times in 1 run."

[image: Challenge list in Race the Sun]

This is proving quite frustrating for me, as I don't actually know how to consistently *do* a barrel roll. I've seen it happen once or twice, but don't really know what I'm doing.

**How do I do a barrel roll?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah-ha! I figured it out!

To perform a barrel roll, you must steer your ship in any *one* direction until you see blue sparkles at the end of your wing. Like this:

[image]

Once you see those sparkles, quickly steer in the opposite directions. You will perform a barrel roll!

<sup>I crashed right into that wall when I took this screenshot.</sup>